# How to call oracle stored procedure using petapoco

Tags: c#, oracle, petapoco

We have recently changed from ADO to Peta Poco.
Connecting to SQL Server is quite easy and is getting familiar with it.
However, I can't find a way to connect to Oracle database. 
These are the syntaxes I tried.

```
var records = db.Execute("ADMIN.ProcedureName @0", param);

var records = db.Fetch<dynamic>("exec ADMIN.ProcedureName ('" + str1 + "','" + recordStart + "','" + recordEnd + "');");
```

Comment: Are you having trouble connecting, or calling a stored procedure?

Comment: Connection with Oracle is fine now. Normal select queries are working. But cannot find a way to call a stored procedure

Comment: Have you tried the stored procedure syntax? https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/wiki/Stored-procedures