# Oracle - Generate POCO's for Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, oracle

I am new to Oracle and I am finding it very hard to get used to it. I am more into code-first Entity Framework and SQL Server. Now, I am working with Oracle and have many stored procedures to deal with.

I want to generate POCO's for the Oracle stored procedures. I didn't find any good solution anywhere.

https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/12/11/sqlqueryresults-code-generation.aspx

Is there any good solution?

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56849740/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedure-using-petapoco)

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica You mean PetaPoco? Never heard and tried it. Let me check